# SQL Reduce Database rows - database size

Tags: sql, database

I have a database that has sales of items by date, so in a given date there might be 800 rows for each item sold in the store. After a while, the table starts getting larger and larger, specially after some years. I can create an algorithm that will add the sales for a day, write a row with that data and instead of having 800 entries, I can have one entry instead. 
Now, is there an easier way to do it with a SQL command. None of my books have a reference and I don't know if there is a command with a fancy name that I just don't know.

Kind Regards,

Daniel Hercules

Comment: You can take your "algorithm" and use it to create a stored procedure that take a product id and a date as inputs. You can then call the procedure in a cursor that loops either products, dates, or both. That would be the simplest way, I think.

Comment: Thin tables with many rows are fine in most databases, I wouldn't worry about it. Now when you have a wide table with denormalized data or a table with multiple values in a single column, that can be a real performance pain.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Comment: I am using access... haha
But I am in the process of migrating it all to mysql and host it online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had a similar problem, with more as 11 milion transaction for one store in one year. I solved this problem with 2 databases on sql server. First database is totally analiticlly database, with all transactions. Every night (after day closure process) i run a job, which groups by store and item (group by sales_date, store_number, item_id) and write into other database (with is "cumulative" database). 
I hope this will help to to think in different direction... :)

Br, DaT

Comment: Thanks so much for the comment. I was just curious if there was perse a method in SQL that did that on its own.
Following your line of thought, after you execute a SELECT * WHERE etc, and select the transactions from one day, how do you write them to another database... one by one? as a whole set?